# Paging List of Objects using LINQ

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq

I have a list of objects `List<Parent> Parents`.

The `Parent` class has a `List<Child> Children`.

Until now, I have applied paging to `Parents` using LINQ:

`List<Parent> PageX = Parents.Skip(PageIndex * PageSize).Take(PageSize);`

For instance, if PageSize=2, I have the following result:

> --------------- Page 1 ----------------------
>
> **Parent 1**
>
> Child 1
>
> Child 2
>
> Child 3
>
> **Parent 2**
>
> Child 1
>
> Child 2
>
> --------------- Page 2 ----------------------
>
> **Parent 3**
>
> Child 1
>
> **Parent 4**
>
> Child 1
>
> Child 2

What I want to achieve is the following:

> --------------- Page 1 ----------------------
>
> **Parent 1**
>
> Child 1
>
> Child 2
>
> --------------- Page 2 ----------------------
>
> Child 3
>
> **Parent 2**
>
> Child 1
>
> --------------- Page 3 ----------------------
>
> Child 2
>
> **Parent 3**
>
> Child 1

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Maybe you're new to LINQ? How would you do it without LINQ?

Comment: It looks like a simple reduction in `PageSize` from the information you have provided.

Comment: If I reduce `PageSize`, then when I get the second page, I would lose some rows.

Comment: How big can your list be? Is this really "in memory" or do you read this from a DB? Because if the list can be very large or you are reading this from the DB maybe another approach is better (e.g. in case of DB only querying the items you actually display)...

Comment: I query only the Ids of parents and the Ids of their Children from the database. All the other data is retrieved for one page only.

Comment: Against a DB it should be possible with one query - I have something here, but I need more information to "adapt it" for you: Are you using EF? Is the parent and the child of the same type (self-referencing)? Are there multiple levels or only one level of parent->children?

Comment: @enb081: Please see my updated answer, how it could work...

Comment: Yes, I am using EF, parent and child are self-referencing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use [`SelectMany`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.selectmany(v=vs.100).aspx):

```
var page = parents.SelectMany(p => p.Children)
               .Skip(PageIndex * PageSize).Take(PageSize);
```

See a working [fiddle here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/MPnp3i).

**Update:**
I did some research as this did interest me also. Using the following assumptions:

- you are using EF
- you have only one level of this parent->children relationship
- your entities have all a `Position` property

you should be able to execute the following against the DB to get the items for a page with the correct order "in one query":

```
var pageItems = db.Parents.SelectMany(p => p.Children).Include(c => c.Parent)
                    .OrderBy(c => c.Parent.Position).ThenBy(c => c.Position)
                    .Skip(PageIndex * PageSize).Take(PageSize);
```

I did not test this code, as I have no DB here at the moment to test it, so please report back, if you can test it, if the assumtions are correct for your case.

Comment: it seems to me that it should be -1 when pageSize (pageIndex * (PageSize-1))

Comment: @W92: I think you mean `(pageIndex - 1) * pageSize`, but IMO an "index" starts at 0 - if it would be `pageNumber`, then I would agree...

Comment: What is the `Position` property used for?

Comment: To order them? If you do not have a "custom order" you could also use e.g. an index or timestamp column...

Comment: I do the ordering when I query the database. Also, `.Include` is not recognized..

Comment: This IS the query to the DB - no other query needed (if it works). For the `Include()` you need `using System.Data.Entity;`...

Answer (score 1):

I am presuming that both `Parent` and `Child` have a common property (say, `Name`) which is used to identify them?

In that case, you would have to flatten the hierarchy to include both parents and children info at the same list level.

So, presuming something like:

```
class Parent
{
    public string Name { get; set; }

    private readonly List<Child> _children = new List<Child>();
    public List<Child> Children
    {
        get { return _children; }
    }
}

class Child
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

You would flatten it to a single `IEnumerable<string>` using:

```
var flattened = Parents
    .Select(p => new [] { p.Name }.Concat(p.Children.Select(c => c.Name)))
    .SelectMany(x => x);
```

And then you page it the way you did so far:

```
var results = flattened.Skip(PageIndex * PageSize).Take(PageSize);
foreach (var x in results)
    Console.WriteLine(x);
```

It would probably be cooler if your `Parent` and `Child` both inherited from the same class or interface.